# ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)'),))

Tags: python, ssl, connection

I am using a package in python , i am trying to access methods with simple print i come up with this error

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.xxxxx.xxx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?gfe_rd=cr&ei=DeCCWZWAKajv8werhIGAAw (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)'),))

is it python error or os level error

please help me in it 
thanks in advance

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your [mcve].

Comment: This error has been thrown by the https library that you are using in Python. Are you using requests or something else? Please post the code snippet that you are using. The error says that the certificate of the server that you are trying to connect to cannot be verified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a pretty much of an idea what you are trying to do with your code. 
The error you are getting is not neither from the python module nor it's an OS error -  it says that the website does not use CA certificates which `requests` module use to request and fetch data

The `requests` modules fails to make successful handshake - it can be possible that you are not allowed to access that website or the website has its own custom security and bots that not working

Fortunately you can create connection pools (proxies) or use httpadapters. `requests` module can also be used to verify certificates so you can try a bunch of things to make it work.

Comment: With the experience of using multiple services.I have noticed the same thing and can be solved as you explained theoretically and practically, This with connection , creating an proxy connection and making the request is solving the issue.

Thanks @CybErNorse